# Jedis pubsub >> "redis-cli config set notify-keyspace-events Ex " doesn't work from conf file

Tags: redis, event-listener, jedis

We have implemented Jedis.expire event , and tend to catch with onPMessage method of KeyExpiredListener class.

```
     KeyExpiredListener extends JedisPubSub {
......
public void onPMessage(String pattern, String channel, String message) {....}
....
}
```

It works perfectly 
when we set .the notify event in Redis cli.

```
redis-cli config set notify-keyspace-events Ex
```

But as expected , if we restart the redis server, the event listener toggles back to default, catching no event , which is same as setting .

```
redis-cli config set notify-keyspace-events ""
```

So we tried to set it in the redis.conf file, But it is not working i.e. not catching any event.

**To summarise**, if we set in cli

```
config set notify-keyspace-events Ex
```

it works, and if we set in conf file (redis.conf)

```
notify-keyspace-events Ex
```

it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Start redis using conf dir -

```
./redis-server <path of redis.conf> &
```

Now (notify-keyspace-events Ex) will work which is mentioned in redis.conf.

Comment: where is this redis.conf placed? I have searched in my machine but can't find. Please help..